# Custom input types in angular 2+

Tags: validation, angular2-forms, angular4-forms, angular-forms, custom-validators

I thought of creating custom validations with custom input types (i.e ) `<input type='dob'>`  for my angular 2 project. I've seen a Q&A in stack overflow which has a solution but which was for angular 1 unfortunately. Can someone help me to get through this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a validator class and static methods for validations.

```
export class CustomValidator{
static nameValidator(control){
   //if valid return true;
  //if invalid return {'errorMsg': 'error desc'};
} 
}
```

You can use the validation like:

```
formData = formBuilder.group({ customValidationField : [[CustomValidator.nameValidator]]  })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use ReactiveFormModule in angular which give you option to build custom form validation

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[ReactiveFormModule,...]
})
------------------------------------------------
myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
   'dateOfBirth': new FormControl(null, [/*here an array of validations*/ this.dateValidation.bind(this)])
})

dateValidation(control: any): {[s: string]: boolean}  {
   if((<dob>control.value).value == '10/08/2017')
     return {'not_old_enough': true}; // if you want to send error
   return null;
)

///// and in html
<form [formGroup]='myFormGroup'>
 <input
    name="dateOfBirth"
    type="dob"
    formControlName='dataOfBirth' />
</form>
```